# Как анимировать рисование подобной фигуры?

Tags: css, css3, svg, анимация, smil

Своял такой текст в illustrator вот такую штуку

Так как сниппет ruSO не пропускает количество символов я выложил SVG в codepen

_https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YBVWKx

Как сделать анимацию рисования ?

Comment: `Как сделать анимацию рисования ?` Можно подробней написать про анимацию?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT типа такого : https://codepen.io/ImagineAndCreate/pen/woZyQv

Comment: ты же умеешь делать анимацию подобного типа `stroke-dashoffset` Вот и сделай здесь самоответом.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT там много class я так не умею ...если бы мог бы я бы уже ответил сам себе

Comment: из детства, раньше такое на уроках рисовали, трубки из кружочков) Я так думаю тут идея создать кривую - путь по которому должна проходить анимация и вдоль этого пути рисовать кружки на расстоянии n px , но все это выглядит ресурсоемким. Но если и я правильно понимаю задачу.

Comment: @HamSter правильно понимаете ... если покажите пример ...это будет круто

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, тут просто svg и smil вряд ли получится, у меня нет идей)

Comment: @HamSter понятно

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Добавлен второй ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовал в качестве кругов символы юникода  `&#10677;`  ⦵

И анимацию вдоль пути, который можно нарисовать любой формы.

`<animate  dur="40s" repeatCount="5" attributeName="startOffset" values="0%;200%;0%"/>`

```css
.container {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <svg  viewBox="0 0 600 400">
 
  <defs>
   <linearGradient id="LG" >
    <stop offset="20%" stop-color="green"/>
 <stop offset="40%" stop-color="crimson"/>
 <stop offset="100%" stop-color="gold"/>
  </linearGradient> 
     <linearGradient id="LG2"  x2="10%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="70%" stop-color="dodgerblue"/>
 <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen"/>
  </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#LG2)" />
 <path id="pathChain" d="m40 110c17.6-37.3 78.8-31.6 120-30 31.6 1.2 58.4 27.9 90 30 88.1 5.8 188.1-101.2 260-50 57.6 41.1 72.8 153.7 30 210C476.9 352.9 291.9 393.8 230 310 179.2 241.3 380.3 149.5 335.9 76.4 303.6 23.1 198.8 12.5 149 66.3 89.9 130 206.9 286 130 300 61.1 312.6 10 173.4 40 110Z" stroke="grey" fill="none"/> 

 <text  font-size="40"  fill="url(#LG)" >
 <textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathChain">
 <tspan >&#10677;  </tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan> 
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan> 
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan>
 <tspan dx="-45">&#10677;</tspan> 
<animate  dur="30s" repeatCount="5" attributeName="startOffset" values="0%;85%;0%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>   
  
</svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: @HamSter смотри, реализовал твою идею, может быть не совсем точно. Создаётся кривая и по ней движутся кружочки. Причем на изгибах они приближаются, удаляются друг от друга, создавая реалистичность

Comment: Саша ну как как объяснить мне ? Ну все же знают этот трюк с dasharray + dashoffset т.е таким образом можно сделать эффект написания текста вот это и надо

Comment: Саша я так же понимаю что там нету dasharray и dashoffset

Comment: Саша этот эффект наблюдается в codepen во время загрузки моего примера в codepen

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Понимаешь, в своем подходе ты напоминаешь дизайнеров, которые нарисуют какой-нибудь эффект и требуют, чтобы он был анимирован с помощью svg/ smil.  А если он теоретически не реализуем? Из-за нарушений непрерывности линий и применения двойных контуров? Что делать? Нужно рисовать новую фигуру с помощью инструмента `"Рисовать кривые Безье"` В этом случае будет одиночный контур.

Comment: Смотри Саша я в codepen обновил пример - там контур не разрывный ...если это не возможно сделать - напиши о этом - я выбиру твой любой ответ как решение хоть он и не подходит

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Очень жаль, что ты не оценил красоту решения. В сети есть конечно примеры с подобными эффектами, но для реализации там просто стена кода на JS/ В первом примере я привел пример решения на CSS от известнейшего мастера

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89185/discussion-between---and-alexandr-tt).

Answer (score 10):

Анимацию на основе изменения атрибута `stroke-dashoffset` сделать невозможно, так как контуры фигуры имеют двойные линии. На рисунке ниже они указаны стрелками. 
Для анимации контура существуют два основных требования: **контур должен быть одиночным и не иметь разрывов.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже смотрите похожий пример анимации, но он реализован на другом принципе: изменении радиуса `r` и положения центра окружности `cx`

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: teal;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}

circle {
  animation: circles 2s alternate infinite cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);
  cy: 15;
}

circle:nth-child(4n+1) {
  fill: darkorange;
}

circle:nth-child(4n+2) {
  fill: gold;
}

circle:nth-child(4n+3) {
  fill: teal;
}

circle:nth-child(4n+4) {
  fill: tomato;
}

circle:nth-child(0) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  cx: 61;
  r: 8.5;
}

circle:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
  cx: 59;
  r: 9;
}

circle:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
  cx: 57;
  r: 9.5;
}

circle:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
  cx: 55;
  r: 10;
}

circle:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
  cx: 53;
  r: 10.5;
}

circle:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -0.75s;
  cx: 51;
  r: 11;
}

circle:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
  cx: 49;
  r: 11.5;
}

circle:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: -1.05s;
  cx: 47;
  r: 12;
}

circle:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: -1.2s;
  cx: 45;
  r: 12.5;
}

circle:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: -1.35s;
  cx: 43;
  r: 13;
}

circle:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: -1.5s;
  cx: 41;
  r: 13.5;
}

circle:nth-child(11) {
  animation-delay: -1.65s;
  cx: 39;
  r: 14;
}

circle:nth-child(12) {
  animation-delay: -1.8s;
  cx: 37;
  r: 14.5;
}

circle:nth-child(13) {
  animation-delay: -1.95s;
  cx: 35;
  r: 15;
}

circle:nth-child(14) {
  animation-delay: -2.1s;
  cx: 33;
  r: 15.5;
}

circle:nth-child(15) {
  animation-delay: -2.25s;
  cx: 31;
  r: 16;
}

circle:nth-child(16) {
  animation-delay: -2.4s;
  cx: 29;
  r: 16.5;
}

circle:nth-child(17) {
  animation-delay: -2.55s;
  cx: 27;
  r: 17;
}

circle:nth-child(18) {
  animation-delay: -2.7s;
  cx: 25;
  r: 17.5;
}

circle:nth-child(19) {
  animation-delay: -2.85s;
  cx: 23;
  r: 18;
}

circle:nth-child(20) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
  cx: 21;
  r: 18.5;
}

circle:nth-child(21) {
  animation-delay: -3.15s;
  cx: 19;
  r: 19;
}

circle:nth-child(22) {
  animation-delay: -3.3s;
  cx: 17;
  r: 19.5;
}

circle:nth-child(23) {
  animation-delay: -3.45s;
  cx: 15;
  r: 20;
}

circle:nth-child(24) {
  animation-delay: -3.6s;
  cx: 13;
  r: 20.5;
}

circle:nth-child(25) {
  animation-delay: -3.75s;
  cx: 11;
  r: 21;
}

circle:nth-child(26) {
  animation-delay: -3.9s;
  cx: 9;
  r: 21.5;
}

circle:nth-child(27) {
  animation-delay: -4.05s;
  cx: 7;
  r: 22;
}

circle:nth-child(28) {
  animation-delay: -4.2s;
  cx: 5;
  r: 22.5;
}

circle:nth-child(29) {
  animation-delay: -4.35s;
  cx: 3;
  r: 23;
}

circle:nth-child(30) {
  animation-delay: -4.5s;
  cx: 1;
  r: 23.5;
}

circle:nth-child(31) {
  animation-delay: -4.65s;
  cx: -1;
  r: 24;
}

circle:nth-child(32) {
  animation-delay: -4.8s;
  cx: -3;
  r: 24.5;
}

circle:nth-child(33) {
  animation-delay: -4.95s;
  cx: -5;
  r: 25;
}

circle:nth-child(34) {
  animation-delay: -5.1s;
  cx: -7;
  r: 25.5;
}

circle:nth-child(35) {
  animation-delay: -5.25s;
  cx: -9;
  r: 26;
}

circle:nth-child(36) {
  animation-delay: -5.4s;
  cx: -11;
  r: 26.5;
}

circle:nth-child(37) {
  animation-delay: -5.55s;
  cx: -13;
  r: 27;
}

circle:nth-child(38) {
  animation-delay: -5.7s;
  cx: -15;
  r: 27.5;
}

circle:nth-child(39) {
  animation-delay: -5.85s;
  cx: -17;
  r: 28;
}

circle:nth-child(40) {
  animation-delay: -6s;
  cx: -19;
  r: 28.5;
}

circle:nth-child(41) {
  animation-delay: -6.15s;
  cx: -21;
  r: 29;
}

circle:nth-child(42) {
  animation-delay: -6.3s;
  cx: -23;
  r: 29.5;
}

circle:nth-child(43) {
  animation-delay: -6.45s;
  cx: -25;
  r: 30;
}

circle:nth-child(44) {
  animation-delay: -6.6s;
  cx: -27;
  r: 30.5;
}

circle:nth-child(45) {
  animation-delay: -6.75s;
  cx: -29;
  r: 31;
}

@keyframes circles {
  to {
    transform: translate(5%, 50%);
  }
}
```

```html
 <svg viewbox="0 -5 70 70">  
  <circle /><circle /><circle /><circle /><circle />
  <circle /><circle /><circle /><circle /><circle />
  <circle /><circle /><circle /><circle /><circle />
  <circle /><circle /><circle /><circle /><circle />
  <circle /><circle /><circle /><circle /><circle />
  <circle /><circle /><circle /><circle /><circle />
  <circle /><circle /><circle /><circle /><circle />
  <circle /><circle /><circle /><circle /><circle />
  <circle /><circle /><circle /><circle /><circle />
</svg>
```

[Источник](https://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/ojKpKz)  @web-tiki

Comment: спасибо но это не то ...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский а вы разве не поняли, что я написал в ответе. Анимировать в том виде, как нарисовано - невозможно из-за двойных контуров окружностей

Comment: плохо ...тогда сделаю через After Effects

Answer (score 2):

Можно изначально скрыть все кружочки, а потом поочередно их показать, получается как-то так:

```js
fetch('https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YBVWKx.html')
  .then(r => r.text())
  .then(html => {
    document.body.innerHTML += html;
    document.querySelectorAll('ellipse').forEach((e,i) => 
      setTimeout(() => e.classList.add('visible'), i*10))
  });
```

```css
ellipse {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 100ms;
}

ellipse.visible{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: @MaximLensky ну на svg тоже можно, только много копи пасты, как собственно и в примере, нужно добавить анимацию появления с разной  задержкой к каждому эллипсу

Comment: и кстати вопрос этот не я задавал