# Как анимировать рукописный текст на веб-странице с помощью SVG

Tags: css, html5, svg, анимация, css-animation

Я пытаюсь анимировать текст, который я создал и сохранил как SVG. До сих пор мне удавалось только оживить `stroke`, но это не то, что я хочу получить.
Вот ссылка на пример, что мне нужно:

[SE7ENSKY Frontend studio](https://codepen.io/se7ensky/pen/waoMyx)

[Handwriting: SVG animation](https://codepen.io/munkholm/pen/EaZJQE)

Я буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь сможет объяснить, как я могу это реализовать.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/37779906/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Как работает анимация `Se7ensky` в вашей ссылке, так это то, что она использует стандартную технику анимации `dash`, но обрезает у анимированной `stroke` выступающий контур, представляющий, нарисованный вручную  логотип.

Стандартная техника анимации `dash` работает следующим образом, - вы берете стандартную линию:

```html
<svg>
  <path d="M 10,75 L 290,75" stroke="red" stroke-width="50"/>
</svg>
```

Затем вы добавляете к стандартной линии `dash pattern` и анимируете его положение изменением `stroke-dashoffset`.

```css
.pen {
  stroke-dasharray: 280 280;
  stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: draw;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path class="pen" d="M 10,75 L 290,75" stroke="red" stroke-width="50"/>
</svg>
```

Наконец, чтобы получить необычную переменную ширину обводки примера `Se7ensky`, вы окружаете эту линию контуром вашего логотипа.

Итак, давайте представим, что этот простой `path` ниже обрисовывает ваш логотип:

```html
<svg>
  <path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="lightgrey"
        d="M 40,50
           C 110,55 195,60, 265,55
           C 290,55 290,85 265,85
           C 195,85 110,85 40,100
           C 0,100 0,50 40,50 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Мы превращаем это в элемент `clipPath` и используем его, чтобы обрезать нашу анимированную строку по форме логотипа:

```css
.pen {
  stroke-dasharray: 280 280;
  stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: draw;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
 <svg>
  <clipPath id="logo">
    <path d="M 40,50
             C 110,55 195,60, 265,55
             C 290,55 290,85 265,85
             C 195,85 110,85 40,100
             C 0,100 0,50 40,50 Z"/>
  </clipPath>
  

 <path class="pen" d="M 10,75 L 290,75" stroke="red" stroke-width="50" clip-path="url(#logo)"/>
</svg>
```

Таким образом, чтобы повторить  пример, указанный по ссылке, вам нужно добавить непрерывный `path`  в SVG, который представляет путь, который выберет перо, как будто оно будет писать буквы в вашем логотипе.

Затем анимируйте этот путь, используя технику `dashoffset`, обрезая его своим оригинальным логотипом.

```css
.pen {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 18;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  clip-path: url(#logo);

  stroke-dasharray: 206 206;
  stroke-dashoffset: 206;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: draw;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 206;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="logo">
      <path d="m85.77 49.77c-10.59 8.017-27.38 21.95-41.58 21.95-6.396 0-12.99-2.481-12.39-9.735l0.3998-4.199c38.38-12.03 48.17-26.15 48.17-35.5 0-7.635-7.995-9.162-14.39-9.162-25.98-0.1909-54.97 25.39-54.17 50.39 0.3998 12.6 7.196 25.01 21.79 25.01 19.79 0 41.78-17.94 53.97-31.5zm-52.37-1.336c5.397-12.6 16.99-21.76 26.98-24.24 1.399-0.3818 2.399 0.7635 2.399 2.1 0.1999 3.245-11.79 16.42-29.38 22.14z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <path d="m39.02 51.1c5.361-1.771 10.04-4.182 15.98-7.857 6.019-3.933 9.841-7.728 12.77-10.71 1.403-1.369 12.03-15.97-7.857-13.93-9.824 1.01-19.62 8.3-26.16 14.91-6.538 6.61-10.42 14.51-11.96 22.23-2.559 12.76 1.807 26.19 21.07 23.48 13.96-1.965 32.59-14.55 43.66-25.54" class="pen"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Интересно, как раз недавно один пользователь задавал подобный вопрос, но там кроме анимированной картинки ничего небыло (закрыли, само-собой). Я ещё тогда подумал, вопрос то в целом интересный, как же всё-таки сделать такое. И вот, как обычно Александр удивил. Спасибо! Беру на вооружение.

Comment: @L.F.C. Благодарю. А ссылку укажешь на тот пост. Я бы ответил с удовольствием. Это действительно очень интересная и полезная техника

Comment: Я сейчас пересмотрю закрытые вопросы, уан момент

Comment: @L.F.C. Я вопрос доработаю и поставлю в очередь на открытие

Comment: @L.F.C. вот ещё одна интересная техника анимации рукописного письма, видимо прошла мимо вас :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/940395/28748

Comment: Я пока что из того что пересмотрел, ничего не нахожу, похоже удалил автор, вкратце смысл, начинает закручиватся как прелоадер, и в процессе переходит в букву логотипа (уже что-то похожее как в этом ответе), использовались зеленый, желтый и синий цвета (точно не помню).

Comment: @L.F.C. Давайте вы сами вопрос задайте тогда, подберите рукописное слово, хорошо бы с кодом SVG, реализующее это слово. А я уже в ответе конкретную технику реализации сделаю. Сделаете?

Comment: Подумаю, может на днях что-то выдам такое. Кстати, недавно [смотрел подобный эффект (как в ответе)](https://codepen.io/ainalem/pen/qKzEyx), но JS задействовал автор